# ¿Cómo crear filtro calendario para gráficos de google chart?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony3, google-chart-api

tengo un problema y es que al momento de construir mi dashboard con google chart, no encuentro cómo hacer un calendario para aplicarle filtro de rango de fecha a la consulta (un controlType del ControlWrapper).

Al investigar en internet, en internet, encontré la siguiente solución (una línea de tiempo), pero no me parece una solución viable ya que si tengo registros de 5 años y quiero aplicar un filtro en específico como 15 días o 1 día, no se podría hacer con precisión:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Conocen de algún control en google charts que me pueda servir?

¡Muchas gracias!